# json conversion fails due to some characters

Tags: jquery, json

The following conversion fails saying bad control character

```
var myObj = JSON.parse('{"imagePath": "http://somedomain.com/test.jpg?path=\728\1.jpg"}');
console.log(myObj);
```

is that because of the following characters "\" in the image path , if so do we have any solution for this?

If i remove that character it works.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how this makes sense, but if you escape it with \\\ it works. `JSON.parse('{"imagePath": "http://somedomain.com/test.jpg?path=\\\\728\\\\1.jpg"}')` why wouldn't just 1 be enough?

Comment: I am getting data that file , when i convert string to object it fails

Comment: No i understand what you are doing, i don't understand why changing it to `path=\\728\\1.jpg` isn't working for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807537/why-does-the-jquery-json-parser-need-double-escaping-for-backslashes

Comment: I am also getting the same error after escaping also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `\` character whereever you are generating the JSON.

If it is a literal, then you have to [escape the escapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807537/why-does-the-jquery-json-parser-need-double-escaping-for-backslashes) also:

```
j = JSON.parse('{"imagePath": "http://somedomain.com/test.jpg?path=\\\\728\\\\1.jpg"}');
```

Comment: Honestly the best solution, if you have influence over whatever is consuming this `imagePath`, is to use *forward slashes* in your paths and avoid this head-ache.

Comment: I will let the service team know

Comment: how can i replace single "\" with four

Comment: If you are typing the string literal in "by hand" in your code, you need to type in 4 `\`.  That's what I meant by *If it is a literal*.  If you are getting the string as data, perhaps from an input field, then you should not be calling `JSON.parse` on it.  It all just works.  If you are receiving the string from the server in a JSON packet, then the server should be using a JSON serializer that serializes the string correctly.

Comment: Here's a jsFiddle showing you only need to do the escapes when you are actually typing the string into your JavaScript code: http://jsfiddle.net/bman654/5dv7s/

Answer (score 1):

`\` is an escape character. So if you want to use `\` in your image Path string, then you need to double escape it. i.e. use `\\`