# C# Serialize JSON turn \ into \\\\

Tags: c#, javascript, json

I am generating JSON for inclusion direction into a HTML file and as such the JSON gets wrapped in a Javascript String.

e.g.

```
var dataContacts = 
        '{"Contacts":[{"Id":0,"Active":false,"Company":"Rory The Architect\\, Melt"}]}';

var contacts = $.parseJSON(dataContacts).Contacts;
```

This code FAILS in javascript because it should be

```
var dataContacts = 
        '{"Contacts":[{"Id":0,"Active":false,"Company":"Rory The Architect\\\\, Melt"}]}';

var contacts = $.parseJSON(dataContacts).Contacts;
```

I've used both .NET Serializer and NewtonSoft.Json and neither have support for turning a \ into a \\\\, they do offcourse turn the \ into a \\ which would be fine for AJAX delivery of JSON but not for JSON embbeded in a Javascript String

I assume I may need to do some sort of myJson.Replace("\", "\\");

I've looked at why I need a \\ in the output, see this link here:

[Why does the jQuery JSON parser need double escaping for backslashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807537/why-does-the-jquery-json-parser-need-double-escaping-for-backslashes)

> The first escape escapes it in the Javascript string literal. The
>   second escape escapes it in the JSON string literal.
>
> The Javascript expression '{"a":"b:\c"}' evaluates to the string
>   '{"a":"b:\c"}'. This string contains a single unescaped \, which must
>   be escaped for JSON. In order to get a string containing \, each \
>   must be escaped in the Javascript expression, resulting in "\\".

I am wondering the best path forward on this issue and why neither NewtonSoft or the .NET serializer have support for encoding JSON for inclusion directly into the Javascript file

Comment: Does `dataContacts.replace('\','\\');` not work?

Comment: "why neither NewtonSoft or the .NET serializer have support for encoding JSON for inclusion directly into the Javascript file" --- why should they? It's a particular language issues. JSON is a language agnostic data format. `NewtonSoft.Json` works with it pretty well.

Comment: NewtonSoft does support encoding JSON for inclusion directly in a JavaScript file, as long as you're doing it the right way. :-)

Comment: @zerkms - I hear what your saying, though I would argue that JSON is Javascript and as such JSON within a Javascript string is a valid USE Case and so support for \ being converted into \\\\ seems reasonable in a library to support example USE Case scenario.

Your thoughts?

Comment: @David See: "that JSON is Javascript" --- nope. It's just a data format that JS supports natively. It doesn't mean that any JSON parser need to take care of details of any programming language out there. My thoughts: JSON parsing library should parse/generate **valid JSON**. If you want to use the JSON string somewhere else - it's *your* responsibility to encode it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you're causing yourself undue trouble by doing things the hard way. Why are you putting JSON into a JavaScript string just so you can immedately parse it? The JSON is already JavaScript, so why not just use it?

```
var dataContacts = 
       {"Contacts":[{"Id":0,"Active":false,"Company":"Rory The Architect\\, Melt"}]};

var contacts = dataContacts.Contacts;
```

And as Paul Draper points out, the approach you're tring to use provides all sort of extra complications once apostrophes and other characters start getting involved.

Comment: Thank you @JLRishe, 

Much easier and more efficient to just store as Javascript than Javascript string followed by Parsing.

As for the apostrophe issues, that was never a worry as I was using both the microsoft and newtonsoft parsers which take care of that. 

My issue was only with the backslash because someone had put a \ into the data and it failed because neither parser could deal with JSON as Javascript string.

Anyway, I don't need to worry about getting that working because the Native notation is more practical.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a second problem here as well, which you have not identified: What if the JSON includes a single quote (`'`), e.g. `Rory's Architect`?

Not only with the Javscript string not be valid JSON, it won't even be valid *Javascript*!

```
var dataContacts = 
    '{"Contacts":[{"Id":0,"Active":false,"Company":"Rory's Architect\\, Melt"}]}';
```

To resolve this, you can do (in C#)

```
string myJsonString = myJson.Replace("\\", "\\\\").Replace("'", "\\'")
```

Note that the escaping the backslashes was necessary in C# to get `\`, `\\`, and `\'`. It's a lot of escaping, all around ;)