# Not being able to parse JSON doue to escape character

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, html-parsing

I have a jsonData like below, I am not able to parse it with`jQuery.parseJSON()` functon due to the presence of escape characters inside the value of the String and it gives me this error:

**Error:**

> SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: bad escaped character at line X column Y of the JSON data"

**jsonData which I am trying to parse using above function:**

```
"reference_data": "{FastDelivery:'[\'facet.delivery.regions.1\'::[{ShippingCountry:\"US\"}]]'}"
```

One of way to enable parsing of this jsonData is by removing that escape character but I  couldn't find any options/right way in Internet/StackOverflow to do it. Can somebody help me here with this small request?

Tried putting extra \ before each \ to make it \ before parsing - but it didnt work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON Parsing error with backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43769456/json-parsing-error-with-backslash)

Comment: I assume by the look of it that the backslash is supposed to be preserved rather than removed (i.e. it should be ``\\``)? Ideally you’d fix whatever is creating the broken JSON instead of adding a parsing hack.

Comment: Who is created json data? you or another side? if you created json data,you need to modified the json creation code.

Comment: unfortunately I am not creating the json data - but it's coming to me (I am pulling it from somewhere) and can only edit it before parsing it and cannot change the source directly.

Comment: @pensum ,  I tried put extra \ before each \ to make it \\ before parsing- but it didn't work