# json_decode is not working on externally received data that has backslashes

Tags: php, json

I receive this JSON data (generated not by me) on my server:

```
{"publicKey": "D2Lxs7gD3cK2Yc+YxJL2iw\dawww1"}
```

When i try to ***json_decode*** it, the result is NULL because of the backslash the string contains. I can't control the string's contents, since i receive it externally.

I tried using ***addslashes*** and ***json_encode*** before i try to decode it, but to no avail.

How can i successfully decode this JSON string?

Comment: Can you use json_last_error() to get the error information an add this information to you question?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43769456/json-parsing-error-with-backslash and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807537/why-does-the-jquery-json-parser-need-double-escaping-for-backslashes - good question, but answered so VTC

Comment: or, php specific version of the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056940/how-to-deal-with-backslashes-in-json-strings-php

Comment: This simply is not (valid) JSON, so you should really complain to the generator of that data, so that they fix the bug in their code.

Comment: For completeness, the _valid_ version would simply be: `{"publicKey": "D2Lxs7gD3cK2Yc+YxJL2iw\\dawww1"}` with a properly escaped backslash. Whoever is producing that data is doing it wrong, and _that_ is what needs to be fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Try escaping these `\` with additional `\`:

```php
$json = str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $json);
```

[Example](https://onlinephp.io?s=s7EvyCjg5eLlUskqzs9TsFVQr1YqKE3KyUz2Tq1UslJQcjHyqSg2T3cxTvY2ikzWjqzw8jHKLI-JSUksLy83VKpVtwbpLkssik8pzS3QAJkSn5KanJ-SqgE2UlNHASyWk1hcEp9aVJRfFJ9bnK6hqWmNQ1dxSVF8UWpBTmJyqoZ6TIy6jgKQBNMQ84A6AQ%2C%2C&v=8.1.8)