# JSON Parse causing 'undefined' json values - Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, undefined

I have searched far and wide for answers to my problem but I am just not winning, I am hoping someone will be kind enough to offer me some guidance.

My below Javascript code is returning undefined json values:

```
var req = '{"testId":"12345","ruleId":"678910","rulePassed":true,"testValue":"C:\\ProgramTest\\"}'

var stringified = JSON.stringify(req);
console.log('stringified json ' + stringified);

//json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(stringified))
var json = JSON.parse(stringified );
console.log('parsed json ' + json);

//testing different ways of pulling out the data, all undefined  
var testId = json["testId"];
var ruleId = json.ruleId;
var testValue = json[testValue];
console.log('testValue ' + testValue);
var rulePassed = Boolean(json[rulePassed]);

njson = '{"testId": "' + testId + '","ruleId": "' + ruleId + '","testValue": "' + testValue + '","rulePassed": ' + rulePassed + '}';
console.log('final json ' + njson);
```

The complication comes in with the backslash in the testValue property.
If I do not stringify the json first, I receive the following error:

SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 143

As soon as I Stringify however, and then parse, the values come back as undefined.

Does anybody perhaps know what I am doing wrong please?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure why you're stringifying a JSON formatted string, you'd normally want to stringify a JavaScript object! Try `var json = JSON.parse(req)` instead.

Comment: yes, but as mentioned, if I remove the stringify function, i receive the following error:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 143 More than happy to hear about a better suggestion?

Comment: if `JSON.parse` is throwing an error on your stringified JSON, then your stringified JSON is formatted incorrectly. There's nothing you can do about that except fix the formatting somehow.

Comment: Which is what I originally tried, I attempted replacing the two backslashes with four - which works, if the JSON is edited - but I receive the following error:

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: You omitted a semi-colon in the first line of your code.

Comment: The reason your values are undefined, is because you're calling stringify on what's already a string. When you parse that string, you get your original string, which of course doesn't have a `testId` or `ruleId` property. Where does this JSON string come from? Do you have control over it in any way? Misformatted json would be an error in the program that provides it.

Comment: you are trying to stringify already stringified json `'{"testId":"12345","ruleId":"678910","rulePassed":true,"testValue":"C:\\ProgramTest\\"}'`

Comment: @UdoE. in javascript, semi-colons are mostly optional lol. That doesn't really affect the question at all

Comment: ok, thanks Khauri, I could ask the developer to send the JSON with 4 backslashes instead of 2 but he was not keen on doing that.

Comment: I figured that this was the problem, and tried to edit the JSON to have four backslashes instead of two - but I am having problems with that - if anyone has advice on doing that, that would also help me.

Comment: I tried:

I tried the following instead:

var req = '{"testId":"12345","ruleId":"678910","rulePassed":true,"testValue":"C:\\ProgramTest\\"}'
req = req.replace('\\','\\\\')
 
//var stringified = JSON.stringify(req);
//console.log('stringified json ' + stringified);
 
var json = JSON.parse(req);
...
but receive the error 
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: @LJR You should encourage them to use a JSON parsing/stringifying library if they aren't already. And make sure that however you receive the string is in the exact same format and encoding as when it is sent. As for a temporary fix, you should read some of the answers on your question.

Comment: @Khauri, it just good practice to include them or just omit all of them if it suits you.

Comment: @UdoE. sure but a missing semi-colon is pretty irrelevant here, yet you presented it as if it was the cause of the problem. If that kind of thing bugs you, you could just edit the question, right?

Comment: @LJR, where did you ever initialize `testValue` before using it in the array key - `var testValue = json[testValue];` ?

Comment: @Khauri Yes I will do that, all the real and helpful answers to my questions popped up after I replied to you.

Comment: thanks all for your comments and help. Issue resolved.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that your data will never properly escape backslashes, a quick solution is the following:

```js
var req_escaped = req.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\") // escape backslashes
JSON.parse(req_escaped)
```

Basically, make your string JSON compliant and then use the usual `parsed` method.

Answer (score 0):

replacing the backslashes compiles. also you need to add " around testValue when you get it from the json

```js
var req = '{"testId":"12345","ruleId":"678910","rulePassed":true,"testValue":"C:\\ProgramTest\\"}';

var req_escaped = req.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\") // escape backslashes
var json = JSON.parse(req_escaped);
console.log(json);
var testId = json["testId"];
var ruleId = json.ruleId;
var testValue = json["testValue"];
console.log('testValue ' + testValue);
var rulePassed = Boolean(json[rulePassed]);

njson = '{"testId": "' + testId + '","ruleId": "' + ruleId + '","testValue": "' + testValue + '","rulePassed": ' + rulePassed + '}';
console.log('final json ' + njson);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the escaping process, the backslashes path should be escaped as follows:

`\\` should be `\\\\`

> The first escape escapes it in the Javascript string literal. The second escape escapes it in the JSON string literal. [Credits and more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3807555/4312466).

```js
var req = '{"testId":"12345","ruleId":"678910","rulePassed":true,"testValue":"C:\\\\ProgramTest\\\\"}'

console.log(JSON.parse(req))
```

Comment: If the answer helped you or answered your question, you can consider upvoting or accepting it! Thanks :)

Comment: oh but I did - unfortunately: 'Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.' - :)